# Get List of Members of a public group from Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I want to get list of ALL members of a public group using Facebook API ( preferably via FQL ).  I checked https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/ .. The table group_member does not provide such API !

Any inputs ? As this is a public group ; do we need to send any auth_access tokens ! Something like [https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20url,normalized_url,share_count,like_count,comment_count,total_count,commentsbox_count,comments_fbid,click_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url='google.com'](https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20url,normalized_url,share_count,like_count,comment_count,total_count,commentsbox_count,comments_fbid,click_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url=%27google.com%27)

works fine without any tokens..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No permissions are needed.

> To read the group_member table you need:
>
> - any valid access_token if the group is public (i.e. the group's
>     privacy setting is OPEN)

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/group_member/

#### Using Graph API

```
GROUP_ID/?fields=members
```

---

```
{
  "id": "GROUP_ID", 
  "members": {
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "User's name", 
        "administrator": false, 
        "id": "User's ID"
      },
      ...
```

#### Using FQL

```
SELECT uid FROM group_member WHERE gid = GROUP_ID
```

---

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "uid": "100004123456789"
    }, 
    ...
```

Comment: Tried http://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20uid%20FROM%20group_member%20WHERE%20gid%20='228346690537926'. It says "An access token is required to request this resource" .. even though its a public group ! How do I generate this access_token.. I am not using any PHP etc. just plain browser.

Comment: Read [this](http://benbiddington.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/facebook-graph-api-getting-access-tokens/) & [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/)! The best way is to go on [the Graph API explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), to get the access token and then to add `&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN` to the FQL or Graph API URL.

Answer (score -1):

just follow this link [https://www.facebook.com/groups/{your](https://www.facebook.com/groups/%7Byour) group id}/apps/store and add your facebook app